# How can I add an option to a field inherited from a parent class?

Tags: django, inheritance

How can I add in my custom class an option to a field existing in the parent model?
More concretely: I'm writing a custom comment model inheriting from `django.contrib.comments.models.Comment`.
I'd like to add the option `editable = False` to the `IPAddressField`.

thank you

Comment: Which class are you inheriting from? Is it `Comment`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way to add an option to an existing field in a super class (if anyone knows better do share). You cannot override the field either as the superclass is not abstract.

If you only want to prevent the field from getting edited you can use a custom model form. This form can validate to make sure that the IP Address field cannot be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't want to display or make it editable in the Admin.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment

class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('ip_address',)

admin.site.unregister(Comment)
admin.site.unregister(Comment, CommentAdmin)
```

Alternatively, you can use ready_only:

```
readonly_fields = ['ip_address']
```

Comment: Not only in the admin. I'll use custom forms. Thanks for the help.